# GoJs Diagram Change HoverDelay Timeout

Tags: gojs

I'd like to allow users to set the hoverDelay diagram option through a form.  How do I/ can I update the hoverDelay value after the diagram has been created?

Here is how i setup my diagram:

```
 this.myDiagram =
            Make(go.Diagram, this._element.nativeElement, // must be the ID or reference to an HTML DIV
                {
                    // start everything in the middle of the viewport
                    initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
                    initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
                    layout: Make(go.LayeredDigraphLayout, { direction: 90, layerSpacing: 10, columnSpacing: 80, setsPortSpots: false }),
                    "animationManager.isInitial": false,
                    hoverDelay : 500
                });
```

starting from the myDiagram object is there a way to update its hoverDelay to say 1000 after the diagram is instantiated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a property of the ToolManager, so you can call:

```
myDiagram.toolManager.hoverDelay = 1000; // or some other number
```

at any time.

Comment: do i need a transaction for this?

Comment: looks like no need for a transaction.  Thanks!